# Phonegap Geolocation on Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap Build version 3.4.0 with the geolocation plugin version 0.3.7.
My app should display the users location on a map.

This works very well under iOS.
But depending on the location settings in Android I am getting very different results.

If I am trying to get a quick location fix with `enableHighAccuracy: false` and the user has disabled *Wireless Location Access*, my error callback gets called with the error code `2`. This is what I expected.

But if I am trying to get the best result with `enableHighAccuracy: true` and the user has disabled *GPS Access* the error callback does not get called. Instead it just times out.

Is this known behaviour and I have to live with it or is there something I could do?

I am using boilerplate code:

```
var positionOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 1000*30,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function positionSuccess(location) {
  console.log(location);
};

function positionError(error) {
  console.log(error);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  positionSuccess, 
  positionError, 
  positionOptions
);
```

**Edit:** this is tested on Huawei/Android 4.0.3, Moto G/Android 4.4.2, Samsung GT-I9100/Android 4.1.2, LG ???/Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 2):

The geolocation on Cordova can be very tricky to get working correctly.  I'm still occasionally battling with it myself.  If you get a timeout make sure the geolocation code is even compatible with your test device by extending the timeout to ~300,000 ms (5 minutes).  Yeah, if you're in a region with a bad signal it can take that long.  Also try getting your location via wifi.  And test on a live device (check out [TestDevice](http://testobject.com)).  Android simulators are iffy.

If geolocation is crucial to your application, you should alert your users of the problem when you get each of these error codes.  Tell your user that they need to enable one form of access or another and how to go about doing that.

Also, you can consider running getCurrentPosition where enableHighAccuracy: false, and if that fails run getCurrentPosition again but this time set enableHighAccuracy: true.  Only after both methods have timed out, prompt the user with an error.

By the way, in my experience while on an Android, Cordova is usually able to lock onto a location within 2-3 seconds when using 3/4G in an urban environment.  If not by then it pretty much never locks on.  Good luck!